# FuelPHP Orm: set() for model with many_to_many relation and table_through

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I have two models, `Model_Post` and `Model_Category`. I've managed to "find" all the related data (easy as $post->$categories), but now I need to create relationships (in the posts_categories table) between a post and multiple categories upon the post's create/update/delete.

Here's Model_Post

```
protected static $_many_many = array(
    'categories' => array(
        'table_through' => 'posts_categories',
        'key_through_from' => 'post_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Category'
    )
);
```

Model_Category

```
protected static $_properties = array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
);

protected static $_many_many = array(
    'posts' => array(
        'table_through' => 'posts_categories',
        'key_through_from' => 'id',
        'key_through_to' => 'post_id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Post'
    )
);
```

posts_categories table fields: `id, name`.

I'm stuck here. How should I build the query?

```
$post->categories = Model_Category::forge()->set(array(
       // I can't get any further
    ),
);
```

Do I need to make a Model for the relationship table as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **many to many** relation to work between the **Post** and **Category** models, you should have three tables in your database: **posts**, **categories** and **categories_posts**.

The first two shouldn't need explanation and the third one is to handle the many/many relation between the two models. It's structure should be similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories_posts`
(
    `category_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `post_id`     BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY   (`category_id`, `post_id`)
);
```

Being **$post** a Model_Post object and **$post->categories** an array for associated categories, we can start working.

To start associating, we forge a new **Model_Category** object and add it to the array:

```
// forge object
$category = Model_Category::forge();

// set name
$category->name = 'Brand New Category';

// associate with Posts
$post->categories[] = $category;

/**
 * we can repeat the last three steps as many times as we want
 * or as many times as we need
 */

// finally, save the relation
if ($post->save(true, true)) {
    echo "Everything OK";
} else {
    echo "Houston, we've got a problem!";
}
```

Notice the two boolean parameters passed to the **save()** method. They are to cascade through the relations and to use transactions respectively. It's a good idea to use that when relating models in one go.

You should read the [ORM documentation](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/intro.html), were you'll find a similar example on [many to many relations](http://fuelphp.com/dev-docs/packages/orm/relations/many_many.html), among other things.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I wanted, and with such ease!